# Maintaining model with separate rigs

Tags: rigging

I hope I can be clear enough as to what I want - The head of the flower rotates on its own so it has it's own rig. The spine moves freely of it's own accord as well, as it should and has it's own rig. My goal is to link the head to the bulb (the sphere between the head and spine) and the spine to that same bulb. In this way, the head can rotate and move freely without affecting the spine and the spine and came move without detaching from the head. Am I completely wrong in how I'm setting the rigs up or am I missing something?

[image]